How to use dual shadows on a list?
I have this SwiftUI app I'm creating. In my styling I use 2 shadows for the objects (like buttons, lists, etc) in the view: The first one is a regular Drop Shadow with some blur, the second one is to create a 3D effect:
.shadow(color: grayShadow, radius: 0, x: 0, y: 3) // 3D effect
.shadow(color: blackShadow, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 3) // Drop shadow

I already got this working on my buttons, which can be seen here:

The problem occurs when i try to apply these shadows to a List. Lists apparently only take one shadow, so only the first one I declare is actually rendered.
Is there a workaround for this? Or maybe there's another way to achieve the 3D effect so the only shadow i need to apply is the regular drop shadow?
EDIT:
Applying these directly onto the list works:
List {
    // content
}
.shadow(color: StyleManager.Colors.grayShadow, radius: 0, x: 0, y: 3) // 3D effect
.shadow(color: StyleManager.Colors.blackShadow, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 3) // Drop shadow

But when i use a seperate file and apply .customListStyle, only one shadow, the first one, gets applied:
List {
    // content
}
.customListStyle()

List style:
struct CustomListStyle: ViewModifier {
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    var shadowColor: Color
    var shadowOffsetY: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background {
                backgroundColor
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .font(StyleManager.Fonts.listTitle)
            .shadow(color: shadowColor, radius: 0, x: 0, y: shadowOffsetY)
            .shadow(color: StyleManager.Colors.blackShadow, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 3) // TODO: Fix the rendering of the second shadow
    }
}

Why is that?

Do you have to use List? If there isn't any List-specific features you need, consider doing this with a LazyVStack in a ScrollView.

@Sweeper What would be some list specific features? My list has some navigationlinks, toggle buttons and a number picker. All hardcoded so no ForEach is being used. In another view i have a list which shows data based on a csv with a toggle feature, so foreach is used.

What ListStyle are you using? I found that applying the shadows to the default list style of .insetGrouped works fine, if you add padding to the list to break the contact with the edges. So are you trying to add the shadows to a Section of the List? A complete example to show how it is not working for you would be helpful.

@BenzyNeez You're right, directly applying them to the list works. I was using a .customliststyle() which got all the styles from a seperate StyleManager file, something went wrong there i guess. I'll have to manually apply them or find out what's causing the issue. Thanks!

@BenzyNeez I edited the post to show my issue.

Your custom list style does not actually implement ListStyle and it probably can't anyway, because this protocol is not intended to be customized (the functions are not documented). Instead, you have defined it as a ViewModifier.
If a .listStyle is not applied to the List then the default style will be .insetGrouped. It seems you are trying to use your view modifier to apply custom styling to the group/section in the list. This is not so easy, because a list section cannot be styled like other containers, it is more like a Group.
However, you can style the list rows themselves. To do this, it is useful to know the following:

A List applies a clip shape with rounded corners to each group/section. This is in fact the main reason why your second shadow is not showing (it is outside the frame of the section, so it is being clipped).
When the list style is .insetGrouped, a List also applies a rectangular clip shape to each row in the list.
The row backgrounds can be styled using .listRowBackground. A solid color works well here and gives the appearance of a continuous background color behind the section.
If you want a continuous border around the section then one technique is to add a border to each row and use negative padding to hide the borders on all inner edges. This is described in the answer to Rounded corners and border for a SwiftUI List Section (it was my answer).

The technique for adding a border to the section can also be used for adding a shadow effect. However, it is necessary to inset the background of each row, so that the shadow is not clipped.
If you want to continue using a ViewModifier as a way of encapsulating the styling then you could define a modifier to apply styling to the rows in the list, rather than to the list itself. For example:
enum RowPosition {
    case first
    case middle
    case last
}

struct CustomListRowStyle: ViewModifier {
    let foregroundColor: Color
    let shadowColor: Color
    let shadowOffsetY: CGFloat
    let position: RowPosition

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.top, position == .first ? 26 : (position == .last ? 6 : 0))
            .padding(.bottom, position == .last ? 26 : (position == .first ? 6 : 0))
            .foregroundStyle(foregroundColor)
            .font(.title3) // StyleManager.Fonts.listTitle
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 4, leading: 30, bottom: 4, trailing: 30))
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowBackground(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 28)
                    .inset(by: 20)
                    .fill(.background)
                    .padding(.top, position == .first ? 0 : -30)
                    .padding(.bottom, position == .last ? 0 : -30)
                    .shadow(color: shadowColor, radius: 0, x: 0, y: shadowOffsetY)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 3)
                    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                        if position != .last {
                            Divider()
                                .padding(.leading, 30)
                                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                        }
                    }
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
            )
    }
}

More notes:

The shadow effect needs quite a lot of space to be shown, so the row background is being inset by 20. The corner radius also has a large value, because it is being inset too.

The list row insets are being applied manually, because the leading and trailing insets need to be larger than the defaults so as to compensate for the inset background.

You will notice that the default row separators are being hidden, then dividers between the rows are being added manually. This is because the default separators do not get inset when the background shape is inset.

The List may apply a rectangular clip shape to each of the rows, but a clip shape is being applied to the backgrounds anyway, just to be sure.


Example use:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(1...10, id: \.self) { n in
            Text("Row \(n)")
                .modifier(CustomListRowStyle(
                    foregroundColor: .green,
                    shadowColor: .yellow,
                    shadowOffsetY: 3,
                    position: n == 1 ? .first : (n == 10 ? .last : .middle)
                ))
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .background(Color(white: 0.8))
    }
}

For this example, list style .grouped is being used instead of .insetGrouped. This is because the rows are now being inset by the styling, they don't need to be inset even more.

See also How do a create a reusable simple custom list style with my own color and spacing for another way of encapsulating the styling for a List.
